# Converting int to string when setting up a hyperlink

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to Microsoft SQL Server but just need a slight alteration to the code below. I'm trying to set up a string which will be used as a hyperlink. It works apart from when I try to add `[fileID]` to the string because `[fileID]` is an integer.

I've tried `CAST` and `CONVERT` but unsure exactly on the syntax to embed them in to this `SELECT` statement. it's just the `[fileID]` part that's wrong.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectBoxes2]
    @bootSaleDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        bootSaleDate,  
        '<br/><video width="100" height="250" src="catalog/videos/' + [fileId] + '" /></a>' AS strText, 
        fileID,
        '<a href="https://www.bargainboxes.co.uk/share-stall.aspx?oid='  + [fileID] + '">View Box</a>' AS link, 
        [buyPrice] AS buyPrice
    FROM 
        [tblItems]
    ORDER BY 
        bootSaleDate DESC
END
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? I can't see `CONVERT` or `CAST` is that SQL. What was wrong with `CONVERT(varchar(10), fileID)`?

Comment: As an aside, generating HTML in your database like this is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just don't know how to insert it properly.. I'm doing this.. 
    SELECT DISTINCT bootSaleDate,  '<br/><video width="100" height="250" src="catalog/videos/' + [filename] + '" /></a>' as strText, fileID,
'<a href="https://www.bargainboxes.co.uk/share-stall.aspx?oid='  + CONVERT(varchar(10), fileID) '">View Box</a>' as link, [buyPrice] as buyPrice, [fileID] as fileID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the [fileId] nullable? If it is the case than you should do this:

```
CAST(ISNULL([fileID],'') AS NVARCHAR(5))
```

Please try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT bootSaleDate, '<br/><video width="100" height="250" src="catalog/videos/' + CAST(ISNULL([fileID],'') AS NVARCHAR(5)) + '" /></a>' as strText, fileID, '<a href="https://www.bargainboxes.co.uk/share-stall.aspx?oid='  + CAST(ISNULL([fileID],'') AS NVARCHAR(5)) + '">View Box</a>' as link, [buyPrice] as buyPrice FROM [tblItems]
```